# Consider the Hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{36}-\frac{y^2}{25}=1$

Tags: geometry

A chord $QPL$ meets an asymptote in $L$ and a tangent from $L$ is drawn touching at $R$. If $PM$, $RE$, $QN$ be drawn parallel to asymptote to meet the other asymptote,

> $$PM+QN= t*RE$$

Than range of $t$ is  ?

**Answer:**

> $t$<$\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: And while you're at it, remember to include what you've tried in order to solve this exercise of yours.

Comment: OK, I will take care of this, can we use mathjax on phone ?

Comment: @XcoderX I have written hyperbola

Comment: @XcoderX what's the mistake ?

Comment: @XcoderX it neither the equation of an ellipse nor an "eclipse". It is really an hyperbola...

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, i realised it is a '-' and not a '+'